# Read two different arrayList value in java and add it to a same array Object

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to create update sql query from csv file.

So, for that I am trying to read two different array list value, one is coming from CSV file and other one is coming from database. I want to update my Books Database but there are some fields which should be as it is.

I wrote below piece of code to do that and I am able to print the query, however I feel my code is not efficient. I could have done this in a more efficient way like instead of reading indexes.

```
public List<Book> generateSqlQuery(List<Book> booksFromCSV) throws Exception{

    String update_query = "UPDATE Books SET book_name={0}, author_name={1}";

    String updateQuery = null;
    Object [] book = null;

    MessageFormat messageFormat = new MessageFormat(update_query);

    List<Book> booksFromDB = BookDao.getBooks();


    for(int i=0; i<booksFromCSV.size()-1; i++){

        book = new Object[] { booksFromDB.get(i).getBookName(),
                booksFromCSV.get(i).getAuthorName()};


        updateQuery = messageFormat.format(book);
        System.out.println(updateQuery);
    }
    return booksFromCSV;
}
```

Please give me some advice or different approaches, of how to read two different arraylist value and keep it in same array.

I apologize in advance for the grammar mistake or any other mistake.

Comment: If both the array lists contain the objects of the same type, then use the `addAll` and add all the items from either list to the other. Then, you can do your process of converting that list to any array of any type.

Answer (score 0):

This could create scenarios of SQL Injection. Use bind variables and loop against the list. If you do believe there are chances of a long list, you can try batch update.